# GWAN query string length issue

Tags: g-wan, server-configuration, http-request-parameters, httpentity

I am using GWAN (v4.3.14) and facing a strange issue. I am trying to pass some long text in the query string. I have figured out that GWAN does not allow me to pass query parameters beyond a total request size of 537 characters.

It responds with a **400 Bad Request**

An example string is :

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/?t.cpp&c=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
```

The code in my C++ file is:

```
# include "gwan.h"
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if(argc)
    {
        cout<<argv[0];
        xbuf_cat(get_reply(argv), argv[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        xbuf_cat(get_reply(argv), "pass something to me to see it on your screen.");
    }

    return 200; 
}
```

Can someone help me to make GWAN accept a query parameter of 1000 characters or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error with G-WAN v4.5+ is ***"414: Request URI too large"***.

Many production HTTP servers disable `PUT/POST Entities` to avoid abuse.

G-WAN first used a limit slightly larger than 4KiB, but most requests do not need so much room so we have made it possible for developers to decide.

The example below (see [entity_size.c](http://gwan.ch/source/entity_size.c) for a working example) shows how to modify the G-WAN (server-global) `PUT/POST Entity` size limit from a servlet but this can also be done in the `init()` or the `main()` calls of a `connection handler`, and from the `gwan/init.c` script available in v4.10+:

```
u32 *max_entity_size = (int*)get_env(argv, MAX_ENTITY_SIZE);
*max_entity_size = 200 * 1024; // new size in bytes (200 KiB)
```

You can change the limit at any time (even while a given user is connected) by using IP filtering in a `connection handler`.

Your servlets will decide what to do with the entity anyway so you can dispose or store on disk or do real-time processing, see the [entity.c](http://gwan.ch/source/entity.c) example.

Beyond this, there are a few things to keep in mind:

- to avoid DoS attacks letting everybody send huge entities to your server (in the GBs), you might enlarge the request size of authorized users only;
- when dealing with requests without a `PUT/POST Entity` you may also dynamically enlarge the read buffer by allocating more memoy to the [READ_XBUF](http://gwan.ch/api#env) by using `xbuf_growto()`.

Now you know how to accept requests of any length. Make sure you do it only when needed.

You may want to check other related values like:

```
  KALIVE_TMO       // time-out in ms for HTTP keep-alives
  REQUEST_TMO      // time-out in ms waiting for request
  MIN_SEND_SPEED   // send rate in bytes/sec (if < close)
  MIN_READ_SPEED   // read rate in bytes/sec (if < close)
```

All of them can be setup from the `gwan/init.c` script - before any request can hit the server. This can also be done from G-WAN handlers and servlets, as shown in the examples cited above.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gil.
I could not find init.c file in the gwan directory.
Also can you tell from where can i download G-WAN v4.5? The latest version available on gwan.com website is v 4.3.14.

Comment: If I remember well, **init.c** is a v4.10+ feature. G-WAN v4.5 was made available to registered users in May 2013, and they currently use v4.12. G-WAN v5 will be publicly available later this year, after our G-WAN-based Cloud services are shipped. Can you accept the answer above? Thanks.

Comment: The suggested solution seems to be for `PUT/POST Entity size limit`. I am trying to do a `GET` with a long query string. Unfortunately in my current usecase `PUT/POST` can not be used.

I have tried the methods you have mentioned but they have not worked out. here is my handler code

`   u32 *max_entity_size = (int*)get_env(argv,  MAX_ENTITY_SIZE); 
   *max_entity_size = 200 * 1024; // new size in bytes (200 KiB)

   xbuf_t * xbuf = (int*)get_env(argv,    READ_XBUF);
   xbuf_growto(xbuf, 200 * 1024);`

Comment: Unlike the Entity size, the **READ_XBUF** value cannot be setup globally (it would not make sense unless all HTTP requests had the same huge length - which is not realistic). Therefore, you have to do it for the current request either AFTER_CONNECT (for example by filtering IPs or authenticated users) and/or when the READ_XBUF size in the AFTER_READ state is out of buffer space. If you have problems with this, send us an email at the G-WAN website.